# Trouble with printer discovery using react-native-esc-pos-printer

Tags: react-native

I am working on a React Native application where I need to implement printer discovery using the `react-native-esc-pos-printer` library. Unfortunately, I am encountering an issue where the printer discovery process doesn't seem to be working as expected.

I am unable to discover printers using the `start` function from the `react-native-esc-pos-printer` library. When I call the `start` function with the appropriate options, the printer discovery doesn't initiate, and no printers are detected. I have double-checked the code and permissions but haven't been able to identify the root cause of the issue.

Discovery.tsx file

```
import React, { memo, useCallback } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import { usePrintersDiscovery, DiscoveryFilterOption } from 'react-native-esc-pos-printer';
import { PrintersList, Button, ScreenTitle } from './components';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

export const Discovery = memo(() => {
  const {
    start,
    printerError,
    isDiscovering,
    printers,
  } = usePrintersDiscovery();

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const handlePrinterPress = useCallback(
    (printer) => {
      if (printer) {
        navigation.navigate('SimplePrint', { printer });
      }
    },
    [navigation]
  );

  const handleSearchPress = useCallback(() => {
    const startDiscoveryProcess = async () => {
      try {
        await start({
          timeout: 10000,
          filterOption: {
            deviceType: DiscoveryFilterOption.TYPE_ALL,
          },
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error starting printer discovery:', error);
      }
    };

    startDiscoveryProcess();
  }, [start]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
        <ScreenTitle title={'Discovery Printer'} />
      </View>
      <PrintersList onPress={handlePrinterPress} printers={printers} />
      <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
        <Button
          loading={isDiscovering}
          title="Search"
          onPress={handleSearchPress}
        />
        {printerError && (
          <Text style={styles.errorText}>{printerError.message}</Text>
        )}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fcf9f9',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

  contentContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

  errorText: {
    color: 'red',
    fontSize: 16,
    marginTop: 20,
  },
});
```

SimplePrint.tsx File

```
import React, { useState, memo, useCallback } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import { usePrintersDiscovery, DiscoveryFilterOption } from 'react-native-esc-pos-printer';
import { PrintersList, Button, ScreenTitle } from './components';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

export const SimplePrint = memo(() => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const { start, printerError, isDiscovering, printers } = usePrintersDiscovery();

  const handleSearchPress = useCallback(() => {
    start({
      timeout: 10000,
      filterOption: {
        deviceType: [
          DiscoveryFilterOption.TYPE_BLUETOOTH,
          DiscoveryFilterOption.TYPE_USB,
        ],
      },
    });
  }, [start]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
        <ScreenTitle title={'Simple Print'} />
      </View>
      <PrintersList
        onPress={(printer) => {
          if (printer) {
            navigation.navigate('SimplePrint', { printer });
          }
        }}
        printers={printers}
      />
      <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
        <Button loading={isDiscovering} title="Search" onPress={handleSearchPress} />
        {printerError ? (
          <Text style={styles.errorText}>{printerError.message}</Text>
        ) : null}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fcf9f9',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

  contentContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },

  errorText: {
    color: 'red',
    fontSize: 16,
    marginTop: 20,
  },
});
```

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.asasiibsc">

    <!-- Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <!-- Use the new Bluetooth Scan API starting from Android 12 -->
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    
    <!-- Update or remove maxSdkVersion as needed -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!-- Main Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- USB Device Attached Intent Filter -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- USB Device Attached Meta-data -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
            android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**What I've Tried:**

1. Checked and ensured that the necessary permissions (Bluetooth, USB, etc.) are granted to the application.
2. Verified that the **`react-native-esc-pos-printer`** library is correctly installed and its version is up-to-date.
3. Examined the compatibility of the devices used for testing to confirm support for the printer discovery process.
4. Reviewed the documentation of the **`react-native-esc-pos-printer`** library for any specific configurations or steps required for printer discovery.

**Expected Outcome:** I expected the **`start`** function from the **`react-native-esc-pos-printer`** library to successfully initiate the printer discovery process and provide a list of discovered printers.